# Polynomial reduction modulo p

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I'm trying to read this research paper, but there's a section I can't understand. So we have this polynomial:

$Q_{k}(z)=z^{6k+7}−8z^{6k+6}+ 26z^{6k+5}−44z^{6k+4}+ 41z^{6k+3}−20z^{6k+2}+ 4z^{6k+1}+ 15z^{4k+6}−72z^{4k+5}+ 138z^{4k+4}−132z^{4k+3}+ 63z^{4k+2}−12z^{4k+1}−12z^{2k+6}+ 63z^{2k+5}−132z^{2k+4}+ 138z^{2k+3}−72z^{2k+2}+ 15z^{2k+1}+ 4z^{6}−20z^{5}+ 41z^{4}−44z^{3}+ 26z^{2}−8z+ 1$

The author did reduction modulo $3$ on $Q_{k}$ and got it factored over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ as:

$\bar{Q}_{k}(z) = (z^{6k+1}+ 1)(z−1)^{4}(z+ 1)^{2}$

Then the author tested for $1$ and $-1$ as roots of $Q_{k}$ (which has multiplicity $4$ and $3$) and concluded that they are the only multiple roots in $Q_{k}$.

My questions are as follows:

- Why do we know they are the only multiple roots of $Q_{k}$ just from the factorization of $\bar{Q}_{k}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{3}$?
- My research advisor said that $3$ is the smallest number we can reduce the polynomial mod $p$. How about $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Here's the link to the paper: [Character Varieties of Knots and Links with symmetries](http://fsu.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fsu:552133/datastream/PDF/view) (page 42)

Thank you for your help and I apologize for the lengthy question.

Comment: Question 2. Of course, we can reduce the polynomial modulo $2$, why not? The question is, what we get. In such a case, you should ask your advisor.  This seems better than that he finds out later here what you wrote.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Thank you for your answer. For question 1, can't $Q_{k}$ have other multiple roots that are not showing up in the factorization of $\bar{Q}_{k}$?

Comment: I see, you mean, how do we know that the original polynomial has no more multiple roots if there are no more modulo $3$? This is not automatically true. But you could use the ususal criterion with the gcd of $f$ and $f'$ for multiple roots.